# How do I stop altered file extensions (from .jsx to .tsx) on a React project's git branch from persisting to an existing branch?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, git, file

I am trying to branch off my React app so I can practise converting files to TypeScript, however when I go to a new branch (typescriptConvert) and change index.jsx to index.tsx, I then check back on my main branch and the file extension has also been changed there too, to .tsx.

I have tried closing and re-opening the file, and resetting VS code as well as 'git clean -xfd' and then re-initialising all the npm packages but still seem to get this issue.

This is the main branch where the extension is still changed to `.tsx`:
[image: this is the main branch where the extension is still changed to .tsx]

Comment: You need to _commit_ the changes to that branch, otherwise they're just in the worktree not actually associated with a specific branch.

Comment: This is a frequent question (I'll try to find the dupe in a second), but basically: uncommited changes do not belong to any one branch, but will be kept around when you switch branches. So either *commit them* on the TS branch or *stash them* before switching.